# Genymotion + VPN

Tags: vpn, genymotion

I am running Genymotion on a MAC. I tried the changed settings in Virtualbox on Adapter 2 to "Bridged" also trying NAT / NAT Network but it does not work. It runs fine on my physical Android device.

I am using Wifi on my Mac to connect to the internet.

Can someone give a hint what i am doing wrong ?

Virtual Box Screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwHmf.png